# How to get list of installed first-level bower packages w/out checking for newer versions?

Tags: bower

`bower list` lists all my installed packages, but also lists sub-dependencies and checks for newer versions.

I don't want to see sub-deps, and I don't want to check for newer versions (I want this to run super fast, no waiting on the network!).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a global `--offline` option that's not listed under `bower list --help`. So, just run:

```
bower list --offline
```

You can try parsing the results of

```
bower list --offline --json
```

to filter out the sub-deps if you like.